# Trying to save score in game. How do you read a SharedPreferences?

Tags: android

I am trying to save a score in my game. I have used a SharedPreferences (line 13-16) to save the score (I think). I would like to know how I could read that SharedPreferences and keep it while the user has left the app. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView textView1;
EditText editText1;
Button button1;
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);}

protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("key", counter);
    editor.commit();}


protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = 0;
    int counter = prefs.getInt("key", defaultValue);


    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);}

public void onClick(View v){
    if (v == button1){
        counter++;
        editText1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));}}}
```

Comment: `SharedPreferences`. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @njzk2 says, You can read it from [Saving Key-Value Sets](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Something like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = 0; // default value for your counter.
int counter = prefs.getInt("key", defaultValue);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had read the documentation to write the SharedPreference. I was getting an error while I was trying to read the SharedPreference.

Comment: It says that it was unable to access variable 'counter'. This was while trying to load the SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

You should load  your SharedPreferences in *onCreate*, and save it in *onPause* or *onStop* or *onDestory*...

[Look at this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, I've switched it around. Now the problem is though that it always restarts at 0. It doesn't actually save it for when the user opens up the app.

Comment: I think you should always save the counter value when you start counting.

Comment: Looks like the SharedPreferences.Editor didn't save, where did you put the commit() ?

Comment: I put the commit() with the onDestroy method. If it's relevant the program is unable to access the counter variable. I am unsure why as I have defined it.

Comment: Try to save score in *onStop*, and load it in *onResume* .

Comment: I agree with @RRTW, try in onStop and onResume. and please insert codes in question where you have using get and set SharedPreferences currently.

Comment: Still no success. I have updated the question with the new code. The 'counter' in line 26 is underlined in yellow, and when highlighted says unable to access variable 'counter'.

Comment: I don't see wrong with code you provided, is that the full code ?